# Retrofit returns 200 response code but I'm receiving null when accessing fields

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, retrofit2, dagger-hilt

I'm using retrofit to make a network request to an API. The response code returns 200 but I am receiving `null` when trying to access the fields. I have checked out other solutions but can't seem to solve my problem. I am using `hilt`

Here is my API class

```
interface BlockIOApi{

   @GET("/api/v2/get_balance/")
   suspend fun getBalance(
   @Query("api_key")
   apiKey: String = BuildConfig.API_KEY
   ): Response<BalanceResponse>
}
```

and here is my app module object

> AppModule

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
object AppModule{
@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideOkHttpClient() = if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
    OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
        .build()
} else OkHttpClient
    .Builder()
    .build()


@Provides
@Singleton
fun providesRetrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit =
    Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build()

@Provides
@Singleton
fun providesApiService(retrofit: Retrofit): BlockIOApi = retrofit.create(BlockIOApi::class.java)
```

}

And finally here is my repositories, **DefaultRepository.kt**

```
class DefaultRepository @Inject constructor(
private val blockIOApi: BlockIOApi,
private val balanceDao: BalanceDao
):BlockIORepository {
override suspend fun getBalance(): Resource<BalanceResponse> {
  return try {
      val response = blockIOApi.getBalance()
      Log.d("TAG", "getBalance>>Response:${response.body()?.balance} ")
      if (response.isSuccessful){
          response.body().let {
              return@let Resource.success(it)
          }
      }else{
          Log.d("TAG", "getBalance: Error Response >>> ${response.message()}")
          Resource.error("An unknown error occured",null)
      }
  }catch (ex :Exception){
      Resource.error("Could not reach the server.Check your internet connection",null)
  }
}
```

and this interface,**BlockIORepository.kt**

```
interface BlockIORepository {
suspend fun getBalance(): Resource<BalanceResponse>
suspend fun insertBalance(balance: Balance)
suspend fun getCachedBalance(): Balance
suspend fun getAddresses(): Resource<DataX>
}
```

Here are my data classes

```
data class BalanceResponse(
val balance: Balance,
val status: String
```

)

```
@Entity
data class Balance(
    val available_balance: String,
    val network: String,
    val pending_received_balance: String,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    var id: Int? = null
)
```

[image]
The problem comes when I try to access the `data` object. I am not getting null for the `status` object
I have been stuck on this for two days now. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is meant by ```receive null when accessing field```? is the value return you null?

Comment: It returns a null value. But however the response code is 200

Comment: Did you check with postman? the returning result have value? Because retrofit will throw exception if the result didn't match with your POJO

Comment: I have updated the question. The problem occurs when trying to access the second object `data`. I have posted the screenshot above

Comment: can you post together with your data class ```BalanceResponse```?

Comment: I had posted my answer down there. but seem someone answer your problem earlier than me haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is occured here:

```
data class BalanceResponse(
   val balance: Balance,  <-- in postman it is "data"
   val status: String
)
```

You should consider putting `@SerializedName(xxx)` for your class.

```
data class BalanceResponse(
   @SerializedName("data") val balance: Balance, 
   val status: String
)
```

Comment: no problem bro! Glad it helps. but make sure to provide details information when asking question :)

Answer (score 1):

Your class should name filed as per the `json` or it should provide `@SerializedName`
So your `BalanceResponse` class should be

```
data class BalanceResponse(
@SerializedName("data")
val balance: Balance,
@SerializedName("status")
val status: String
)
```

Since you are trying to hold `data` in `balance`, you must provide `SerializedName`, but if they have the same name and with exact-case then the parser will automatically recognize them.